# inline bracket, similar to a permutation and binomial, but aligned

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, inline

I'm often experiencing instances, when I need to define a function on two sets in a domain. I'd like to create a command `\newcommand{\func}[4]{...}`, which makes an **inline bracket**, that shows how the function maps both sets of points.

So far, I've managed to do this

[image]

via the command `$\binom{\tiny(x,s,t)\mapsto(x,s(1-t))}{\tiny(y,t)\mapsto y~~~~~~~~~}`. As you can see, I'm having problems with the **alignment** of both `\mapsto`s and also with the **size** of the both outer brackets.

Could anyone please help me write such a command? I tried it with an inline table, but it is way too large. It would be desirable (but not necessary) that both outer brackets would respond to `\left` and `\right` or `\big`.

COMMENT: this is how my current solution (via \binom with no alignment) looks like:

[image]

Any solution that produces larger brackets is not acceptable. The only thing that is missing is alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, one would have a version of `aligned` with smaller spacing. I'm not aware of any implementation of that though.

Here is a non-automatic solution with `\mathllap` and `psmallmatrix*` from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
abc 
$\begin{psmallmatrix*}[l]
    (x,s,t)                           \mapsto (x,s(1-t)) \\ 
    \phantom{(x,s,t)}\mathllap{(y,t)} \mapsto y
\end{psmallmatrix*}$
abc
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: @Caramdir: LaTeX Error: Environment psmallmatrix* undefined!

Comment: and this is still quite large, looks larger than \binom

Comment: how do people in algebra write inline permutations? those are aligned

Comment: @Leon: Did you include `mathtools` (this probably needs a recent version)? Smaller text would be unreadable. You could get smaller brackets by using `smallmatrix*` (without `p`) and putting in brackets of your own, but imo the brackets in your example are too small.

Comment: @Caramdir: Last request, I promise: the main problem are the brackets inside. If you zoom in, you can see that in (x,s,t), the bracket is by far the tallest symbol, taking most of the space. How can I use some other type of braces inside this command, that are only as tall as the largest symbol?

Comment: to clarify: I'm asking for an environment being added to the inside of the command \func.

Comment: @Leon: This is how the Computer Modern fonts are designed. It will be hard to change the size of the brackets and still have them look good.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an option, building on Tobi's answer. Now the command offers three different sizes depending on the first (optional argument): with no optional argument, it can be used in in-line expressions; using `Big` or `bigg` as the optional argument, you can increase the size and use the command in displayed expressions.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

% default values
\newcommand\OpenS{\bigl(}
\newcommand\CloseS{\bigr)}
\newcommand\Vspace{-0.85em}
\newcommand\Msize{\scriptstyle}

\newcommand{\func}[5][]{%
  \ensuremath{% 
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{Big}}
      {\renewcommand\OpenS{\Bigl(}%
        \renewcommand\CloseS{\Bigr)}%
        \renewcommand\Vspace{-0.55em}%
        \renewcommand\Msize{\textstyle}}%
      {\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{bigg}}%
        {\renewcommand\OpenS{\biggl(}%
          \renewcommand\CloseS{\biggr)}%
          \renewcommand\Vspace{-0.2em}%
          \renewcommand\Msize{\displaystyle}}%
          {}}
          \OpenS%
            \begin{aligned}\Msize
            {\Msize#2} &\mapsto {\Msize#3}\\[\Vspace]
            {\Msize#4} &\mapsto {\Msize#5}
            \end{aligned}
        \CloseS%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
text text  text text t text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text text text $k(g)=\func{(x,s,t)}{(x,s(t-1))}{(y,t)}{y}$ text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  
\[
k(g)=\func[Big]{(x,s,t)}{(x,s(t-1))}{(y,t)}{y}
\]
text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text 
\[
k(g)=\func[bigg]{(x,s,t)}{\big(x,s(t-1)\big)}{(y,t)}{y}
\]
text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text 

\end{document}
```

The result:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this (note that you’ll need the `amsmath`-package):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\func}[4]{%
    \ensuremath{%
        \left(%
            \begin{aligned}
            #1 &\rightarrow #2\\
            #3 &\rightarrow  #4
            \end{aligned}
        \right)%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\[k(g)=\func{abcd}{ef}{gh}{ijklm}\]
\end{document}
```

output:
[image: output]

You just have to replace the arrows …

Comment: way too large to be inline. This is much larger than \binom

Comment: @Leon I don’t believe, that somebody likes to read an construct like this inline ;). If you like you can wrap it in an `\resizebox` from the `graphicx`-package

Comment: The things that I'm writing are fairly simple functions (concrete homotopies). It's much more readable, if it's written in this way.

Comment: @Leon, Tobi: you can shrink this by putting `\scriptstyle` in front of each of the four parts, and putting `\\[-10pt]`  for the line break.  The number may need tuning.  Also, use `\bigl(...\bigr)` for the braces and it looks pretty inline to me.

Answer (score 2):

This is a streamlined version of Gonzalo's answer

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ho@func}[8]{
  %#1 = opening delimiter
  %#2 = closing delimiter
  %#3 = vertical space 
  %#4 = size of symbols
  %#5 = top left
  %#6 = top right
  %#7 = bottom left
  %#8 = bottom right
  #1\vcenter{\halign{\hfil$##\mapsto{}$&$##$\hfil\cr
    #4#5&#4#6\cr\noalign{\vskip#3}#4#7&#4#8\cr}}#2}
\@namedef{ho@}{\ho@func{\bigl(}{\bigr)}{-1ex}{\scriptstyle}}
\@namedef{ho@Big}{\ho@func{\Bigl(}{\Bigr)}{-.2ex}{\textstyle}}
\@namedef{ho@bigg}{\ho@func{\biggl(}{\biggr)}{0ex}{\textstyle}}
\newcommand{\func}[1][]{\@nameuse{ho@#1}}
\makeatother
```

The optional argument to `\func` decides which one of the `\ho@...` commands to use; the command `\ho@...` expands to `\ho@func` followed by four of the eight arguments it requires, the following four are in the input stream,where they appear to the user as arguments to `\func`.

I too, as Phil, would never define such a thing using `\ensuremath`: putting math formulas where they belong helps to confine syntax errors.

Note: edited to use directly `\halign`. The example text can be the same as in Gonzalo's answer, no extra package is needed.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm afraid this is too complicated for me. Especially since I've found a better solution (I think). I can't post it yet, I have to wait 8hrs, not enough reputation points.

Comment: @Leon: You don't need to understand the definitions, just to use them. :) The example text may be the same as Gonzalo's.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version using Xy-pic:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\newcommand{\func}[4]{
  \begingroup
  \let\objectstyle=\scriptstyle
  \ensuremath{
    \left(
      \vcenter{
        \xymatrix@R=0ex@C=1em{
          {#1} \ar@{|->}[r]& {#2}\\
          {#3} \ar@{|->}[r]& {#4}
        }
      }
    \right)
  }
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

Here we are in math mode: $\func{(x,y)}{x+y}{(s,t)}{s^{2}-t}$

Here we are not in math mode: \func{(x,s,t)}{(x,s(1-t))}{(y,t)}{y}

\end{document}
```

(I would never have thought of using `\ensuremath`, but I saw it in @Tobi's answer.)
[image]